# Getting Invalid grant, malformed auth code while verifying token on server side

Tags: java, google-oauth

We are trying to use Google OAuth in our product. The flow would be to get Client get the auth from the users and send the token to server. On server side I need to verify the token is valid. For now, I am using OAuth2Sample provided by Google as client. when I verify the sent token on server side, I am getting the following exception:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>
> {
>     "error" : "invalid_grant",
>     "error_description" : "Malformed auth code."
>   }
>
> at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
>
> at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
>   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)

Here is the code on the server side:

```
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
              new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                  new NetHttpTransport(),
                  JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",

                  CLIENT_ID,
                  CLIENT_SECRET,

                  authToken, //Sent from the client
                  "")  // specify an empty string if you do not have redirect URL
                  .execute();
```

Here is how I get the accesstoken on the client side:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
//...

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, 
clientSecrets, //Client ID and Client Secret
SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(
        dataStoreFactory).build();

LocalServerReceiver lsr = new LocalServerReceiver();
Credential cr = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, lsr).authorize("user");
return cr.getAccessToken(); //send this to server for verification
```

The token is not corrupted on the way to server and it is:

> ya29.Glx_BUjV_zIiDzq0oYMqoXkxz8VGzt8GCQuBiaaJ3FxN0qaLxbBXvnWXjNKZbpeu4jraoEqw6Mj9D7LpTx_8Ts_8TH0VGT5cbrooGcAOF0wKMc1DDEjm6p5m-MvtFA

If I try to access profile and email from the client side, it works fine. Same token does not work on the server side gets malformed token exception.

Comment: did you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 24):

I am using `Node.js` googleapis client library, Here is my case:

The authorization code in the url hash fragment is encoded by `encodeURIComponent` api, so if you pass this code to request access token. It will throw an error:

`{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Malformed auth code." }`

So I use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the authorization code.

```
decodeURIComponent('4%2F_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY')
```

After decode, the authorization code is:

```
"4/_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY"
```

In Java, maybe you can use `URLDecoder.decode` handle the code.

Comment: All of a sudden it seems Google is encoding the auth code now. Although I was using Postman, but decoding the auth code did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might face this in the future. I faced this issue and `decodeURIComponent` **did** **not** work with me. The previous answers work with for different issue.

From the question itself, you can see that the token starts with `ya29.`

```
ya29.Glx_BUjV_zIiDzq0oYMqoXkxz8VGzt8GCQuBiaaJ3FxN0qaLxbBXvnWXjNKZbpeu4jraoEqw6Mj9D7LpTx_8Ts_8TH0VGT5cbrooGcAOF0wKMc1DDEjm6p5m-MvtFA
```

That indicates that the token is an online token. In case of the online login, you can see that the response looks like this [image]

But that will not work with server side login. So, when using some Google client library, please note that there are two variables that you need to check:

- access_type: `offline`
- responseType: `code`

Once you configure Google client library with those fields, you can see that the response of the login will change to something like this

```
{
    "code": "4/0AX4XfWgaJJc3bsUYZugm5-Y5lPu3muSfUqCrpY5KZoGEGAHuw0jrkg_xkD_RX-6bNUq-vA"
}
```

Then you can send that code to the backend and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

we do get this error when for some reason the call back url of the auth is called a second time. The first time it works but the second time it errors out.

Not sure how the users are able to do that. Maybe by pressing the back button in the browser.

The error is indeed this:

```
{"error": "invalid_grant","error_description": "Malformed auth code."}
```

Encoding the code in the call back URL was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to slideshowp2's answer, and Subhadeep Banerjee's comment.

I am using server-side web app with HTTP/REST ,also facing the same problem
and yes, the reason is that authorization code return from URL is encoded.

After decode, everything work fine to get access token.

p.s. here is some info about [encodedURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

since our Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded