# Gmail API, get new access token after revoke

Tags: java, spring, gmail-api

I'm developing application that provides access to gmail mailbox. I created new project and logged in with few email accounts. When I revoked access token through this endpoint: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke, the number of accounts attached to my project didn't change.
When i try to select account again, google redirects me to uri I specified, but code within url is corrupted and I can't get new access token using code from this url.
Response i get using code from url:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Malformed auth code."
}
How can i completely log out from my app?

```
Credential authorize=getCredentials(gmailMailBox, emailProperties.getGoogleClientSecrets());         
authorize.refreshToken();
Unirest.post(emailProperties.getRevokeTokenUrl(authorize.getAccessToken()));
```

getCredentials method:

```
Credential authorize = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())                 
.setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())                 
.setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)                 
.build()                 
.setAccessToken(gmailMailBox.getAccessToken())                 
.setRefreshToken(gmailMailBox.getRefreshToken());
```

```
private Credential getCredentials(GmailMailBox gmailMailBox, GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
                .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
                .build()
                .setAccessToken(gmailMailBox.getAccessToken())
                .setRefreshToken(gmailMailBox.getRefreshToken());
    }
```

```
public class GmailMailBox {

    private String accessToken;

    private String refreshToken;

    private LocalDateTime expiresIn;
}
```

```
public GoogleClientSecrets getGoogleClientSecrets() {
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = new GoogleClientSecrets();
        GoogleClientSecrets.Details clientSecretsDetails = new GoogleClientSecrets.Details();
        clientSecretsDetails.set("client_id", client_id);
        clientSecretsDetails.set("project_id", project_id);
        clientSecretsDetails.set("auth_uri", auth_uri);
        clientSecretsDetails.set("token_uri", token_uri);
        clientSecretsDetails.set("auth_provider_x509_cert_url", auth_provider_x509_cert_url);
        clientSecretsDetails.set("client_secret", client_secret);
        clientSecrets.setWeb(clientSecretsDetails);
        return clientSecrets;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to revoke the token and to get a new access token?

Comment: `Unirest.post(https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token={access_token});` I used unirest for post request with refreshed token.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the OAuth flow you're following?

Comment: I'm using GoogleCredentialBuilder to create Credential object and get new access token first. `Credential authorize = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
                .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
                .build()
                .setAccessToken(gmailMailBox.getAccessToken())
                .setRefreshToken(gmailMailBox.getRefreshToken());
` Then I use new access token with unirest request.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this?: `When i try to select account again, google redirects me to uri I specified, but code within url is corrupted and I can't get new access token using code from this url.`. Also, please consider providing the code related to `gmailMailBox`, editing your question accordingly. Finally [GoogleCredential](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html) is deprecated, I'd suggest you to use [this library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java).

Comment: I'm using below url to access account selection page. After selection I'm redirected to specified redirect_uri and I can get code from url. However after token was previously revoked and I select account again, the code is corrupted. It seems like my gmail account is hooked to my project. How can I log out completely from my project and deny access to my mailbox. https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
scope={scope}&
access_type=offline&
include_granted_scopes=true&
response_type=code&
state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&
client_id={id}

Comment: I'm thinking the problem might be that you didn't delete the token file that was generated the first time you completed the OAuth flow, so it's trying to use an access token that was revoked. Can you please check if that's the case?

Comment: ```Credential authorize = getCredentials(gmailMailBox, emailProperties.getGoogleClientSecrets());
        authorize.refreshToken();
        Unirest.post(emailProperties.getRevokeTokenUrl(authorize.getAccessToken()));``` I store tokens in database. I get new access token before revoke. You mean that i might be using old token?

Comment: That's an hypothesis. Could you please provide the code related to how you're getting the credentials? Things like `gmailMailBox` and `getCredentials`.

Comment: I added more code. The point is to give user possibility to deny access to gmail from my app and completely log out from project i created in google api console.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a sample of the authorization code you got? I'm thinking your problem might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311417).

Comment: Thanks, that was it, however i still have a problem. After I revoke access token and I want to get new access and refresh token using decoded code I get:{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}. Endpoint I'm using: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token and parameters: code, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, grant_type(authorization-code). This endpoint works when I log in to my app for the first time.